# How to convert String format in Scala

Tags: scala

> 我有一个String的字符串是类似这样的
>
> `232302001A7102186410045298B9A000A00000E100010160120903130108920050433630315F433133302E3030342E3132372E30315F54312E312E3000000064666266356135326137613464633039633430650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001005D28`
>   内容;现在我想将它转化为`23,23,02,00, 1A`等这样的形式,但是不知道怎么做,想了半天没一点思路,>求大神指点一下***

Comment: english please.

Comment: can you describe your question in english please.

Comment: I have a string of String is similar to such a "232302001A7102186410045298B9A000A00000E" content , now I want to convert it into such a form, such as '23 , 23 , 02 , 00 ,1A', but do not know how to do, think for a long time without a bit of thought, ask God to give some advice

Comment: very very thank you (I'm a little rookie, hee hee)

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716418/5986907 perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you can do.

```
val str = "232302001A710218641004529" +
    "8B9A000A00000E100010160120903130108920050433630315F433133302E3030342E31" +
    "32372E30315F54312E312E300000006466626635613532613761346463303963343065" +
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001005D28"

  val ans = str.sliding(2,2).toList
  println(ans)
//List(23, 23, 02, 00, 1A, 71, 02, 18, 64, 10, 04, 52, 98, B9, A0, 00, A0, 00, 00, E1, 00, 01, 01, 60, 12, 09, 03, 13, 01, 08, 92, 00, 50, 43, 36, 30, 31, 5F, 43, 31, 33, 30, 2E, 30, 30, 34, 2E, 31, 32, 37, 2E, 30, 31, 5F, 54, 31, 2E, 31, 2E, 30, 00, 00, 00, 64, 66, 62, 66, 35, 61, 35, 32, 61, 37, 61, 34, 64, 63, 30, 39, 63, 34, 30, 65, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 5D, 28)
```

Or you can use grouped as the value of m,n is equal we should use grouped. Like this

```
str.grouped(2)
```

Comment: May I have your email? I want to add you (if you don't want to), I want to learn from you (forgive me for being a rookie, and my English is very common)

Comment: what ever you want to learn there are lots of people to help you so just keep asking question you will learn and sorry i can't give any personal information. If i solved your problem please accept answer @梁liang

Comment: ok, thank you , I'm too abrupt.

Answer (score 0):

This can be archived using `.grouped` method like follows:

```
val string = "232302001A710218641004529"

val res = string.grouped(2).toList
// res: List[String] = List("23", "23", "02", "00", "1A", ...)
```

*I think it's clearer than `.sliding` with two params.*