# How to process chunks of a big xml payload individually in scala

Tags: xml, scala, xml-parsing

I have big xml payload which i'm getting sometimes/ i'm getting it as below (example)

```
  <items>
<item>
  <property>1</property>
  <property2>2</property2> 
  <nested-property>
    <property>1</property>
  </nested-property>   
</item>
<item>
  <property>1</property>
  <property2>2</property2> 
  <nested-property>
    <property>1</property>
  </nested-property>   
</item>
<item>
  <property>1</property>
  <property2>2</property2> 
  <nested-property>
    <property>1</property>
  </nested-property>   
</item>
<item>
  <property>1</property>
  <property2>2</property2> 
  <nested-property>
    <property>1</property>
  </nested-property>   
</item>
...
...
...
```

Now I need to select say n elements each time and send them to a downstream system, how do i do this in scala?

Comment: Maybe take a look to [this](https://fs2-data.gnieh.org/) or [this](https://www.scalawilliam.com/xml-streaming-for-scala/) or [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/xml.html)

Comment: the xml payload seems to be very big which is too big to be sent to downstream

Answer (score 0):

Found and easier way to do this ...

```
xmlData = XML.loadString(paylaod)
val = xmlData \ "items" \ "item"

chunkSize = 50

xmlData.toList.grouped(chunkSize)
.toList.map(list => "<items>" + list.mkString("") + "</items>")
.toNel
```

now i have a list of chunked xml, which i can later process each chunked/grouped data. a bit too crude solution though

found the grouping solution on this link
[How can I break a collection into batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716418/how-can-i-break-a-collection-into-batches)